# SQL Union Query where same field has different name in two tables

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have two tables in which the same field is referenced differently (`city_id` and `geo_name_id`) I can't really change this, as they play different roles in both tables. I want to execute the following two queries on both tables and then combine the results into one where the returned field is called `city_id` :

`SELECT city_id FROM user_city WHERE user_id = '$user_id' UNION SELECT geo_name_id as 'city_id' FROM cities WHERE featured = 'yes'`

This seems to work fine, however I'm not sure if I have taken the right approach here.

Comment: From your problem description using `union` is the correct approach.

Comment: I was referring more to the `Select geo_name_id as 'city_id'` part of the query, I wanted to know if this would result in the union working properly and naming all the returned fields as city_id

Comment: Yes it will do what you want and expect.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help :)

Comment: you don't even need to worry about the 2nd part of it. As long as the data types match up, it succeeds and uses the column names supplied by the first query. You can even do `as whatever` for the alias on the second query